# moving heroku db to RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, heroku

I'm trying to move a postgres db (version `9.6.15`) we have in heroku public space that I want to move to AWS RDS. The db is about 2.2tb and its on heroku premium 7 tier.

Since I see that its pretty much impossible to do a live replication from heroku since they limit the functionality of setting up replication (from my understanding), I'm looking to see how fast I can dump the data and load it to RDS.

I was looking at ways to optimize `pg_dumps` and what I did so far was run it from an ec2 instance (m5.2xlarge) in AWS to see how fast `pg_dumps` would run.

When running it on the ec2, I've only been able to get to 10mb/sec which is crazy slow because in that sense, it would take about 84hrs to run.

I ran `pg_dumps` as such:

```
sudo pg_dump postgres://user:pass@url:5432/db \
--jobs=24 \
--format=directory \
--file=/monodb/pgdump2 \
--verbose
```

what else can I do to speed up the exports, or is this just a limitation on the egress bandwidth from heroku?

Comment: Have you tried to do pg_dump from other location, i.e. start it locally just to measure  download speed? 10mb/sec is a hard limit for physical backup (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-data-safety-and-continuous-protection), for pg_dump rate should not by capped by any limit except of capabilities of the db instance itself.

Comment: yeah...I've tried both from an VM on AWS and GCP...both appear to be running at the same download rate on `iftop` when I look, starts at around ~3Gb at the 2second rate and then slowly drops off to ~500Mb at the 2nd rate over the course of the `pg_dump`.

Comment: If the limit is on egress from heroku, then there's probably not much you can do - have you verified that?  Can you test a dump from inside the same network to see if that performs any better?

Comment: are u concern about speed? if not you could look into aws database migration service

Comment: AWS DMS wouldn't work here unfortunately, Heroku doesn't allow certain permission to allow that to happen

Answer (score 0):

**1. Dump your schema separately from the data**

The reason for this will be more clear as your read on but simply put, dumping the schema separately allows us to have multiple concurrent dump and restore operations going at once.

**2. Disable foreign keys prior to beginning a restore**

A Postgres dump, typically, is a sequence of insert statements. If the table you are inserting into has foreign keys, then the rules of the keys must be evaluated for every insert.

```
create table if not exists dropped_foreign_keys (
       seq bigserial primary key,

       sql text

);

do $$ declare t record;

begin

   for t in select conrelid::regclass::varchar table_name, conname constraint_name,

           pg_catalog.pg_get_constraintdef(r.oid, true) constraint_definition

           from pg_catalog.pg_constraint r

           where r.contype = ‘f’

           — current schema only:

           and r.connamespace = (select n.oid from pg_namespace n where n.nspname = current_schema())

       loop

       insert into dropped_foreign_keys (sql) values (

           format(‘alter table %s add constraint %s %s’,

               quote_ident(t.table_name), quote_ident(t.constraint_name), t.constraint_definition));

       execute format(‘alter table %s drop constraint %s’, quote_ident(t.table_name), quote_ident(t.constraint_name));

   end loop;

end $$;
```

After you are done restoring data, you can re-enable the foreign keys by running the following command:

```
do $$ declare t record;

begin

   — order by seq for easier troubleshooting when data does not satisfy FKs

   for t in select * from dropped_foreign_keys order by seq loop

       execute t.sql;

       delete from dropped_foreign_keys where seq = t.seq;

   end loop;

end $$;
```

**3. You can you different flags for pg_dump with your current flags such as:**

```
–data-only – This is the flag to dump only the data from the tables and not the schema information.

–no-synchronized-snapshots – Prior to Postgres 9.2 this a requirement for running jobs in parallel

–schema=public – Instructs pg_dump to only dump the public schemas, for most cases this is all you need.
```

**4. Dump large tables by themselves and group small tables together**

Doing this allows you to run multiple dumps and restores at the same time. You can specify the tables you want to group together by using the –table flag in pg_dump.

[Reference link for more detail](https://blog.iseatz.com/speeding-up-postgres-data-dumps/)

Comment: I don't think you can change the `postgres.conf` file in Heroku...right?